# pd.to_datetime() not working on a column with different date formats

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I wrote a program where a dataframe is traversed & when any column with the name 'Date' is encountered, all the rows under that column are supposed to be converted to a 'datetime' object using 'pd.to_datetime' in the format mentioned. But this method is not working for me.

The 'Date' column in my dataset consists of dates in various formats & with different separators. **Example: 26/04/2007, 01-15-1998, 2020-12-2**. When I do debugging I get an error message for those dates that are not in the format specified.

Isn't the whole point of using the method a way to convert dates in any format to a datetime object & in the format specified?

My code:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
import re
from datetime import datetime
import calendar

import pandas as pd

def date_fun(filepath):
     
   date_list=['Date', 'date', 'Dates', 'dates']
   
   for i in filepath.columns:
 
      for j in date_list:     
          if i==j:
            filepath[i]=pd.to_datetime(filepath[i], format='%d-%m-%Y')
           
                                                                         

main_path = pd.read_csv('C:/Data_Cleansing/lockdown_us.csv')
fpath=main_path.copy()


date_fun(fpath)
```

**Error**: **time data '26-2016-09' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y' (match)**

Where is the mistake in my code?

Comment: The error is self explanatory, this cell contains a date that is not in the expected format, first coerce all dates to have the same format then cast to date using the method.

Comment: Could you provide an example input row, please.

Comment: call `pd.to_datetime` without a `format` argument tells pandas to guess to format. And it **usually** guess correctly: `df[date_list] = df[date_list].apply(pd.to_datetime)`.

Comment: **Note**: your variable is `filepath`, but you pass in a dataframe, which is a little strange.